# How can I use mongoDB advanced filters in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

IO want to know that how can I query the Mongo DB as  I am doing  in the bash specially 
advanced filters to get my desired output

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of examples (in java also) on the official documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status = "D"
```

Turns into something like that (in java):

```
collection.find(eq("status", "D"));
```

And so on..

Answer (score 0):

Just use CrudRepository and create your query:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

E.G.

Create a interface and add your custom query:

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

And if it's very complicated use the query annotation:

```
@Query("select u from User u")
```